# syntax error: operand expected (error token is "/ ")

Tags: bash, shell, nagios

```
DSKUSDPERCENT=$(($DISKUSD * 100 / $limit))
```

throws an error like

```
syntax error: operand expected (error token is "/ ")
```

where limit=$OPTARG defined in Process command line options

Here I am not able to get the value of `$limit`

Comment: Run the code with `set -x` turned on. Most likely `limit` is blank.

Comment: `if test 0 -lt "$#"; then`. Neither the command substitution nor the subshell are necessary. (In fact, they are actively harmful; `test` produces no output, and a shell with no command trivially succeeds; you have a complicated way of writing `if true; then ...`.) Run your code through shellcheck.net before asking questions here.

Comment: `doopts $@` is broken. **Always** quote your arguments: `doopts "$@"` -- and edit to fix the other bugs https://shellcheck.net/ shows you too. A `set -x` log would be extremely useful, since it would show us which arguments your script (and thus `doopts`) was actually passed. If you don't pass a limit argument in practice, we would expect this error.

Answer (score 1):

Check `$limit` value:

```
$ DISKUSD="1000"
$ limit="100"
$ echo $(($DISKUSD * 100 / $limit))
1000
$ limit=''
$ echo $(($DISKUSD * 100 / $limit))
bash: 1000 * 100 / : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "/ ")
```

So, it is likely that `$limit` is empty, so that the expression becomes something like `$((666 * 100 / ))`, which is, of course, invalid.

> where limit=$OPTARG

Well, either there's no command line option for limit is provided, or there's some mistake in processing arguments.

Comment: thanks for the prompt response, I couldn't follow your answer. could you please provide more description

Comment: @Rahul, I've expanded it a bit

Comment: how can I correct this [syntax error: operand expected (error token is "/ ")], I am bit confused

Comment: @Rahul, the code you're posted is correct.  The "syntax error" is because `$limit` is empty (or not defined), but we can't help you fix it, because you haven't posted the code that's supposed to have `$limit` defined/set.

Comment: @
Nikolaj Š., updated more details

Comment: @Rahul, post the whole script and how you run it.  Your code snippet can't be run, and even after a bit of fiddling with it I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Also, _chepner_'s suggestion to run the code through shellcheck is an absolute must.

Comment: @Rahul, it's helpful that you're now posting the whole script, but you left out the "and how you run it". If we don't know that you're passing `-l` with a valid limit value, then we still don't know that limit should be gegtting set.

Comment: @Charles Duffy, I am able to run by passing "-p filesystem" and able to get/see the value of available space but % disk used could not able to get due to limit is null.. Also validated using shellcheck

Comment: @Rahul, you can't _only_ pass `-p filesystem`; the way your script is written you **must** also pass `-l limit` with a valid number in place of `limit`. If you don't want that, update your code to have smarter handling for what to do when no limit is set.